# How to remove all empty tags from xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

my xml is :

```
    <content type="text/html" title="flow-active-timeout">
<body>    
    <dl>
    </dl>
    <p>&#160;</p>

    <div mt-section-origin="Product_Documentation/Command_Reference/Configuration_Commands/flow-active-timeout" class="mt-section" id="section_1"><span id="vManage_Feature_Template"></span><h2 class="editable">vManage Feature Template</h2>

    <p>For vSmart controllers:</p>

    <p>Configuration &#9658; Policies&#160;&#9658; Centralized Policy</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

and my xslt code is :

```
<xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')))]"/>
```

but it removes only empty `<p>` tag not `<dl>` tag

Output using above xslt:

```
<body>
<dl/>
<div mt-section-origin="Product_Documentation/Command_Reference/Configuration_Commands/flow-active-timeout" class="mt-section" id="section_1"><span id="vManage_Feature_Template"></span><h2 class="editable">vManage Feature Template</h2>

    <p>For vSmart controllers:</p>

    <p>Configuration &#9658; Policies&#160;&#9658; Centralized Policy</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

expected output is :

```
    <body>
<div mt-section-origin="Product_Documentation/Command_Reference/Configuration_Commands/flow-active-timeout" class="mt-section" id="section_1"><span id="vManage_Feature_Template"></span><h2 class="editable">vManage Feature Template</h2>

    <p>For vSmart controllers:</p>

    <p>Configuration &#9658; Policies&#160;&#9658; Centralized Policy</p>

    </div>
</body>
```

Please provide some statement to achieve the expected output

Comment: using these two statements together i can achieve the expected output  <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')))]"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" />                                                             but I need one generic statement.

Comment: Are you sure you existing template does not remove `dt` as it looks fine to me. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6r5Gh2M. Have you got any other templates that might be matching `dl` that have a higher priority perhaps? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps there is a higher-priority template rule that matches the dl elements somewhere in your stylesheet? Or perhaps you are never applying templates to those elements? Without a repro, we can't know.

Comment: Also, if you had an element like `<dl><dt /><dd /></dl>`, with both `dt` and `dd` being empty, would you then want `dl` removing too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="*[text()='&#160;' or  normalize-space(.)='']"/>
You may also use like this
```

Comment: I have applied these two statements to remove the empty tags which is working fine for me <xsl:template match="*[not(normalize-space(translate(., '&#160;', ' ')))]"/>
<xsl:template match="*[not(node())]" />
but now my requirement is except emty <img src S00987.png/> tag all other empty tags should be removed..Please provide some solution to achieve this.

Comment: I am using <xsl:template match="*[text()=' '  or text()='&#160;' or normalize-space(.)=''][not(self::img)]" /> but it removes all the empty tags including img.Could you please suggest how can I remove all empty tags except img tag

Comment: <xsl:template match="*[text()='&#160;'  and not(self::img) or  normalize-space(.)=''and not(self::img)]"/>
You may also use like this